# Django messes up the order of load tags?

Tags: python, django

I am using navbar of [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/examples/offcanvas/) project, in my django project (Bootstarp 4.6). Here is the code:

**Base.html :**

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" href="{% static 'images/favicon.png' %}">
  <!--Bootstarp CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--Bootstarp CSS ENDs-->
  <!--CSS-->
  {% block css %}{% endblock %}
  <!--CSS ENDs-->
  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--Navbar-->
  {% include 'quicky/navbar.html' %}
  <!--Navbar ENDs-->

  {% block content %} {% endblock %}

  <!--Bootstrap JS-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--Bootstrap JS ENDs-->
  <!--JS-->
  {% block js %}{% endblock %}
  <!--JS ENDs-->
</body>

</html>
```

**Navbar.html :**

```html
{% load static %} {% block css %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/quicky/navbar.css' %}"> {% endblock %}


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto mr-lg-0" href="#">Offcanvas navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler p-0 border-0" type="button" data-toggle="offcanvas">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

  <div class="navbar-collapse offcanvas-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Notifications</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Switch account</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Settings</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="nav-scroller bg-white shadow-sm">
  <nav class="nav nav-underline">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Dashboard</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
        Friends
        <span class="badge badge-pill bg-light align-text-bottom">27</span>
      </a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Explore</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Suggestions</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </nav>
</div>


{% block js %}
<script src="{% static 'js/quicky/navbar.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

And this is the **navbar.js** file placed in static folder.

```js
$(function () {
    'use strict'
  
    $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').on('click', function () {
      $('.offcanvas-collapse').toggleClass('open')
    })
})
```

In the console I am getting this error.

- Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

I believe this error occurs because the navbar.js file, for some reason is not able to have the jquery. But if you see the Base.html file I first loaded the bootstrap files and then I placed the {% block js %}. So that first the jquery gets loaded and then my navbar.js file would come.

Also if I remove those block elements and write the contents of navbar.js file directly in Base.html I do not get this error.

- What is the problem with the `{% block js %}`?

Comment: I feel like you just didn't close your `{% block css %}`. Could it be that?

Comment: The include tag **does not** fill the current templates blocks, so your assumption that it fills that block js of yours is false and which is why you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the static files including a function which requires jquery before you actually load the jquery library. This is why you are getting the error  `$ is not defined` since `$` is defined/instantiated in `jquery`

Try this - manually add the `navbar.js`  to your `index.html` page after the jquery library and confirm that the error goes away. If it does, then it means your issue is with your load sequence.

Comment: I understand that the issue is with the load sequence, but my question is that in Base.html file I actually wrote the script tag to load jquery first, and after that i added `{% block js %}` so should'nt html first load those tags and then go to the tag. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I don't see that you are loading the script tag first in your base.html file. The first thing in your base.html file is the static include function and it doesn't appear to be 'deferred'. Your script tags are at the bottom of the file and will load after 'navbar.html' loads

Comment: Thanks adding defer tag to only my js and not bootstrap js fixed the issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

The template included by an `include` tag is independent (except perhaps with regards to the context) of the including template. From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#include):

> The
> [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-include)
> tag should be considered as an implementation of “render this
> subtemplate and include the HTML”, not as “parse this subtemplate and
> include its contents as if it were part of the parent”. This means
> that there is no shared state between included templates – each
> include is a completely independent rendering process.

That is the blocks of the including template or the blocks of the templates which extend the including template are not at all related to the included template.

You should simply render that script tag (and any other things that you expect to be filled in the parent blocks templates) separately in your base template:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/quicky/navbar.js' %}"></script>
{% block js %}{% endblock %}
```

Or if you want to be able to remove this tag by extending the template:

```
<!-- in base template -->
{% block js %}
    <script src="{% static 'js/quicky/navbar.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}


<!-- in children templates keeping the navbar js -->
{% block js %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <script src="{% static 'js/someother.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}


<!-- in children templates NOT keeping the navbar js -->
{% block js %}
    <!-- Since we dont render block.super it is not rendered anymore -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/someother.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```